# Websocket: onmessage is not called but only on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, websocket

we have a problem regarding Websocket Communication with a Windows-Client.
As minimal setup we use the python3 autobahn websocket ping-pong example.

The server is from (taken from https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/asyncio/websocket/echo/server.py). The only modification is that the server sends a message to the client when the connection is opened.

The client is also taken form the autobahn pingpong example but modified in two ways. It accepts connections from a remote server and it does not send a message to the server but it expects one.

This does work well on all browsers on my Linux Machine, but it does not work from a Windows-Client. But if I send a message from the client as soon as the connection is opened, then the client is also able to receive the messages.

Here is the pyhton3 server:

```pyhton
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
    WebSocketServerFactory


class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, req.uest):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")
        self.sendMessage('server hello'.encode('utf8'))

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
        else:
            print("Text message received: {0}".format(payload.decode('utf8')))

        # echo back message verbatim
        self.sendMessage(payload, isBinary)

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import asyncio

    factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://0.0.0.0:9000", debug=False)
    factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(factory, '0.0.0.0', 9000)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        server.close()
        loop.close()
```

Here is the Websocket Client:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var socket = null;
         var isopen = false;

         window.onload = function() {

            socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.hostname + ":9000");

            socket.onopen = function() {
               console.log("Connected!");
               isopen = true;
               //if I do this, then it works
               //socket.send('hello from client'.encode('utf-8'))
            }

            socket.onmessage = function(e) {
               console.log("Text message received: " + e.data);
            }

            socket.onclose = function(e) {
               console.log("Connection closed.");
               socket = null;
               isopen = false;
            }
         };
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Has anybody an idea what I am missing? I want to open a connection from server to client without sending a message from the client first.

Comment: strange problem. i tryed it at windows 7 with node.js websocket server and python websocket server.

the server sends a 'hello' immediately after the connection is opened. at some ports the client gets the message, at other ports not (mindless of node.js or python at server).

Comment: ah, i can't edit my comment again. so here the rest:
i checked the communication with wireshark. at hypertext transfer protocol are all messages identical, except an "X-FCCKV2" Header at HTTP Get message with "Upgrade: websocket" from the client. I haven't found, what the X-FCCKV2 header do and why it is added sometime from the client (at all browses: chrome, firefox, ie).